# Detecting "=" instead of "==" typo in if condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, g++

Is there a way to make g++ yield a compilation error if I use `=` instead of `==` inside of an if condition in c++? I've made this typo a couple times, and it's annoying to track down. That is:

```
if (x=5){ //bad - sets x equal to 5
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `-Wall` flag would at least warn you about this (and lots of other stuff).

Comment: Another style of coding that basically eliminates this problem is to reverse the order of the comparison. I.e `if (5==x)` will always cause an error if you forget the second `=` symbol.

Comment: @enhzflep As long as one of the terms is a constant.

Comment: I use `-Wall -Wextra` and it notifies me of all kinds of stuff like that.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: for builtin types you can exacerbate the horror by using unary `operator+` to create rvalues: `if (+x = y)` fails to compile, so type `if (+x == y)`. Or, rather, don't.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - good point. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Wparentheses` option specifically warns such cases, which is also a part of `-Wall` option.

From [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -Wparentheses
>
> > Warn if parentheses are omitted in certain contexts, such as when there is an assignment in a context where a truth value is expected,
> >     or when operators are nested whose precedence people often get
> >     confused about.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > When there is the potential for this confusion, GCC will issue a warning when this flag is specified. **To eliminate the warning, add explicit braces around the innermost if statement so there is no way the else could belong to the enclosing if.**

which can converted into an error using by specifying `-Werror=parentheses`.

Note that

```
if(x=5) {...}
```

is legal and standard requires no such diagnostics. But an implementation is allowed to provide any number of such useful warnings.

Comment: In order to use the assignment (legally) and not get a warning, gcc allows you to nest the parens, ie `if ((x=5)) {...}` will not generate a warning.  It is best practice to avoid statements with side-effects though, and make your code simpler and more readable by putting the assignment on one line and the conditional on the next line.

Comment: @MarkLakata It depends. Sometimes you can't get much more readable than `while ((bytes = read(fd, buffer, buffer_size)) >= 0)`. You can remove the assignment by using some helper function, but in simple cases like this that can actually reduce readability. There's always an exception to rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can address this with a different coding style: a lot of programmers I know prefer to use the style `if (5 == x)` for this reason, because if you forget an equals sign then you get `if (5 = x)` which does not compile (5 is not an lvalue).

Aside from being a bit simpler than tinkering with compiler options, it is also portable to any standard C++ compiler.

IMO, the only downside is that it doesn't read as naturally if you're not used to it; in English it's more common to say "if x is equal to 5" instead of "if 5 is equal to x."  Of course since equality is commutative, both are correct, but most people prefer the former.  This is one of those cases where something that seems wrong from a stylistic perspective does help you write more maintainable code.

Comment: Another problem is that in case of `if (x = y)` (both are lvalues) it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Yoda condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) is a simple, compiler independant solution: `if (5=x){statement}` will not compile.